# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH- on my site RiteOnPolish.com

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I've tried reading through posts and using PHP to modify the wp-content file folder.
I've followed multiple tries but all fail.  I cannot access the wp-admin editor in any way.

I'm a bit of a newb and was trying to add the required SSL certificates to enable a WooCommerce shopping on my website.  My SSL cert is from Cloudflare.  I tried going to CF and turning off certificate, however, something in the site is preventing me from accessing the very basics!  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to fix this, but this website might help.
scroll down for the part about SSL Errors
[Presslabs.com](https://www.presslabs.com/how-to/err_too_many_redirects-and-err_ssl_version_or_cipher_mismatch/)